# Chat multi client sockets

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, chat, port

I'm using `System.Net.Sockets;` and `System.Net;`, so trying to find some useful information about how to create multi client sockets for desktop chat application. Now I have chat between two clients and it is connected as 81 and 80 and vise-versa for client from textboxes

```
epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
sck.Bind(epLocal);

epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox3.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text)); 
sck.Connect(epRemote);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Hello, I'm trying to figure out how to make it work for several clients, and I'm not sure how to do it proper way. For example if I have 3 clients online in chat, each must see answers and questions from two others. What I have now, it is chat between two parts

Comment: In order to see messages from each client, each client would have to be (indirectly) connected to every other client. Usually this is done by introducing a server - all other clients connect to this server. You could choose to make the client that creates the "chat room" the server, or you could create a dedicated server (that isn't a client) to which each client connects.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis your answer is helpful, I found good options for this implementation